# add to collection in sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Maybe my question is very simple and superficial
But please, guide me

my Place Model is:

```
module.exports = {
attributes: {

title: {
  type: 'string',
},

body: {
  type: 'string',
  columnType: 'text',
},

address: {
  type: 'string',
  columnType: 'text',
},

x_map: {
  type: 'number',
  columnType: 'float'
},

y_map: {
  type: 'number',
  columnType: 'float'
},

like: {
  type: 'number',
  columnType: 'integer'
},

dis_like: {
  type: 'number',
  columnType: 'integer'
},

visited: {
  type: 'number',
  columnType: 'integer'
},

emtiaz: {
  type: 'number',
  columnType: 'integer'
},

tags: {
  type: 'string',
},

city:{
  collection: 'city',
  via: 'place_owner'
},
},
};
```

And my City Model is:

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
title: {
  type: 'string',
},



ostan_owner :{
  model: 'ostan'
},

place_owner: {
  model: 'place'
  }
 },
};
```

And my place controller is:

```
create: function (req, res, next) {
Place.create(req.params.all, function place_created(err,new_place){
  if(err && err.invalidAttributes) {
    err = validator(Place, err);
    return res.json({'status':false, 'errors':err.Errors});
  }
  else{
    new_place.add('city',req.param('city'));
    new_place.save(function (err) {
      if(err){
        return res.json({'status':false,'errors':err});
      }
      else {
        res.json({'status':true,'result':new_place});
      }
    });

  }


});
},
```

now whene i try to create new place and add new city to collection it give me Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined  
at place_created (C:\Programing_workspace\gardeshgar_sailsV1\gardeshgar\api\controllers\PlaceController.js:28:19)
```

whene i use model_X.addToCollection i recive same error
i use sails v 1.0 and i am new in sails.js

please Help me

Comment: When you do `new_place.add('city',req.param('city'));` it fails because you haven't defined `new_place` anywhere

Comment: @bugs but new_place is defined in function place_created(err,new_place)

Comment: I'm not familiar with that type of syntax, but to me that looks like a function that takes `new_place` as an argument, it doesn't seem to create it

Comment: this is a callback function.function place_created is called just whene Place.create() is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sails.js 1.0 does not support `.add()` and `.save()` anymore.
Please use `.addToCollection()` instead.

```
await Place.addToCollection(new_place.id, 'city').members(req.param('city'));
```

The other problem is that sails.js 1.0 does not automatically fetch the created/updated Object (new_place in your case). 
You need to add `{ fetch: true }` in order the get the created object.

For example:

```
User.create({...}, function(err, createdUser) {
//...
}, { fetch: true });
```

Or using await:

```
var createdUser = await User.create({...}).fetch();
```

I think, in your case, the solution should be:

```
create: function (req, res, next) {
  Place.create(req.params.all, function place_created(err,new_place){
    if(err && err.invalidAttributes) {
      err = validator(Place, err);
      return res.json({'status':false, 'errors':err.Errors});
    }
    else{
      await Place.addToCollection(new_place.id, 'city').members(req.param('city')).exec(function (err) {
        if(err){
          return res.json({'status':false,'errors':err});
        }
        else {
          res.json({'status':true,'result':new_place});
        }
      });          
    }   
  }, { fetch: true });
},
```